# What are the good ARIMA models for this time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I have an exercise in which the plot of the time series $X$, its ACF, and its PACF are given. Moreover, the plot of the time series $Y = \text{diff}(X)$, its ACF, and its PACF are also given.

From plots of $X$, I propose $X \sim AR(3)$. From plots of $Y$, I propose $X \sim ARIMA(10,2,1)$. Could you please evaluate my model suggestions?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `X` can be `AR(1)` and `Y` can be `ARIMA(14,3,1)`

Comment: @Duck, your suggestions are incompatible since $Y_t = \Delta X_t$. ARIMA(14,3,1) does not seem adequate at all; how come you suggest third-order differencing?

Comment: @RichardHardy You are right. High values are below confidence limits!